# Raspberry pi 3B+ not booting up ( ACT light / green light doesn't blink at all)

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-stretch, act

I have an old raspberry pi 3B+. After a long time, I tried to use it. I found raspbian stretch image file in an old archive. So I wrote it in a 32GB microSD card and tried to boot the pi. But the ACT light(green) doesn't glow at all.

**Things I tried**

- Re write the image file to sd card ( I know the img file is not
  corrupted as I remember using it previously and it worked ).
- I checked the 3V3 pin, and it is working ( so I haven't fused or
  burnt my pi ).
- I tried it with another SD card, still it doesn't help.

I went through the internet but could't find any troubleshooting methods other than the above. Help me to boot my little old friend [ her name is ANA :) ].

Comment: Try your SDCard in another RPi. If it boots OK then send your 3B+ to the recycling and replace it with a RPi4B 2GB.

Comment: what did you use to write the image to the SDCARD? Also, have you tried using the latest image (Raspberry pi OS Buster) to see if that works

Comment: Follow the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) and tell us what step fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a fresh installation using the latest operating system.  I noticed similar thing when I tried running a stretch OS that I upgraded from Jessie. But when i tried using a freshly installed Buster OS, it booted normally.